# How to alert everything in the body (using TamperMonkey)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

```
function main() {
   var text = $('body').text();
   alert(text);
}

setTimeout(function(){main();}, 2000);
```

I want everything in the body alerted after 2 seconds, but I can't seem to get it to work, I'd appreciate if somebody could help, thanks!

Comment: Seems to work if I paste the code into my console in Chrome..can you be more precise as what is not working?

Comment: That would work (assuming you're using jQuery on purpose). The setTimeout can be simpler: `setTimeout(main, 2000);` But it works as-is as well.

Comment: Be aware you're using jQuery in `$('body')`

Comment: So what happens? Wait for the body to load incase 2000ms is not long enough? - `$(function() { setTimeout(function(){main();}, 2000); });`

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsbin.com/zuqije/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I'm using this on TamperMonkey, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: use : alert($('body').html()) inside your function.

Comment: Please add more relevant code if you have, e.g. how you set your contents to begin with.

Comment: Works for me **in Tampermonkey**.